# How do I run a multicraft Minecraft server backup locally on my desktop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I used to run a server on a hosted setup that used Multicraft.  I have a backup of the directory (zip file generated from the host's interface) as it existed before I cancelled service.  Is it possible to run this locally?  If so, what do I need to do to get it running?  I'm pretty sure I was running Bukkit based off of 1.7.2, if that matters.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by backup of the directory? What is in the root of the zip file? Is it a world backup, server backup, multicraft backup?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I generated it via the host's interface, not multicraft.  The server was through exodus hosting.  They have an interface to manage the "account" which was separate from the multicraft interface.  I'm pretty sure it's a backup of my directory's contents on the server.

Comment: So could you tell me what was in the zip file? As in the root of the zip file. Open up the zip file and tell me the files you see without navigating to other folders.

Answer (score 1):

The type of server you run depends on you and what was installed before, If you had a lot of plugins that you cant live without install bukkit. If you had mods then you would need to install Forge.

Also depends on whether you wanted to play with other people or just turn it into a single player world.

For single player just copy the world folder into your saves folder in the .minecraft directory.

For multiplayer you can run a server locally but you may need to port forward.

I use a program call [Minecraft Server Dashboard](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1265318-minecraft-server-dashboard) which i find very simple to use with a really nice UI.

You can download older server jars from [here](https://mcversions.net/) so you just need to download the 1.7.2 jar.

Unfortunately Bukkit is kinda hard to get a hold of for 1.7+ atm due to legal reasons but hopefully will be up again soon. but you could use the 1.7.2 version of [Spigot](http://www.spigotmc.org/) which works in much the same way as bukkit and has a strong community behind it.

If you need to use [forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) you can download the installer for 1.7.2 and it will install all the required files.

Once you have the server jar running just replace the generated world with the one in your backup, and you will be running the server just like it was before.

For port forwarding information look [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177448/how-do-i-port-forward-minecraft)